# Can not add category link to wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I had tried to add category link to the menu, but there is no category lists under the Categories.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

Check the screen option button in the right corner. to select the 'Product categories' option. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes vou can add categories, on admin panel in your left you can see Categories chose de category and add on the menu, and save